# What to do if npm shows unresolved vulnerabilities?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, npm, webpack, angular12

I upgraded an angular aspnet core app from 10 to 12 and now I have bunch of denial of service vulnerabilities which has no fix.

I dont understand how is it released even? Whats the prod deployment strategy with Angular 12 ?

```
css-what  <5.0.1
Severity: high
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1754
No fix available
node_modules/css-what
  css-select  <=3.1.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of css-what                                                                                                                                          node_modules/css-select                                                                                                                                                      17:22    svgo  >=1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      postcss-svgo  >=4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/postcss-svgo
        cssnano-preset-default  *
        Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss-svgo
        node_modules/cssnano-preset-default
          cssnano  >=4.0.0-nightly.2020.1.9
          Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano-preset-default
          node_modules/cssnano
            css-minimizer-webpack-plugin  *
            Depends on vulnerable versions of cssnano
            node_modules/css-minimizer-webpack-plugin
              @angular-devkit/build-angular  *
              Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-webpack
              Depends on vulnerable versions of css-minimizer-webpack-plugin
              Depends on vulnerable versions of sass-loader
              Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
              node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular

glob-parent  <5.1.2
Severity: moderate
Regular expression denial of service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1751
No fix available
node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/glob-parent
  chokidar  1.0.0-rc1 - 2.1.8
  Depends on vulnerable versions of glob-parent
  node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/chokidar
    webpack-dev-server  2.0.0-beta - 3.11.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of chokidar
    node_modules/webpack-dev-server
      @angular-devkit/build-angular  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-webpack
      Depends on vulnerable versions of css-minimizer-webpack-plugin
      Depends on vulnerable versions of sass-loader
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
      node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
      @angular-devkit/build-webpack  *
      Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server
      node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-webpack

trim-newlines  <3.0.1 || =4.0.0
Severity: high
Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1753
No fix available
node_modules/trim-newlines
  meow  3.4.0 - 5.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of trim-newlines
  node_modules/meow
    node-sass  3.5.0-beta.1 - 6.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of meow
    node_modules/node-sass
      sass-loader  5.0.0 - 6.0.7 || 8.0.0 - 10.1.1 || 11.0.0 - 11.0.1
      Depends on vulnerable versions of node-sass
      node_modules/sass-loader
        @angular-devkit/build-angular  *
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @angular-devkit/build-webpack
        Depends on vulnerable versions of css-minimizer-webpack-plugin                                                                                                                      Depends on vulnerable versions of sass-loader                                                                                                                                       Depends on vulnerable versions of webpack-dev-server                                                                                                                                node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      16 vulnerabilities (4 moderate, 12 high)
```

Comment: What do you mean _"how is it released even"_ - how is _what_ released? _"Whats the prod deployment strategy"_ - we don't know what _your_ deployment strategy is, or do you mean someone else's (whose?)

Comment: I guess: "how can Angular be released when it depends on a few thousand packages with all sorts of known unfixed vulnerabilities"

Comment: If that is the question: what are you expecting the maintainers to do? Those vulnerabilities weren't disclosed when Angular 12 was released, and don't yet have fixes. Once those fixes become available, maybe they won't be semver-compatible and will have to trickle up through upgrades to the other packages in the tree. Even if they'd been known at 12.0 release time, do you stop the whole thing due to these vulnerabilities (especially given they're in the build tooling)?

Comment: are you telling me that releasing an angular app to prod with known DoS holes is normal practice and I should not be bothered? is that so?

Comment: Lol yes that's _exactly_ what I said. If you're not comfortable releasing your app while there are any vulnerabilities in the dependency tree, by all means don't; I can't tell you what your and your organisation's appetite for risk is.